# Reload div at checkbox click

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Is it possible for me to reload a div when a checkbox in the same document is clicked?

```
<html:checkbox property="checkbox" styleId="checkbox">
<div id="divToBeRefreshed">
    //content
</div>
```

I'd rather do it using pure javascript but ajax is ok too if there isn't another solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well the answer by @karthick is for change event it will reload the content if the checkbox is unchecked also you can use the below code

```
$('#checkbox').change(function(){

    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        // Checkbox is checked.
        $("#divToBeRefreshed").html('your content');
    }else{
        // Checkbox is not checked.
    }   

});
```

make your id of checkbox is set to

```
id='checkbox'
```

Hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $("#checkbox").on('change',function(){
       $("#divToBeRefreshed").html('your content');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `change` event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to `<input> elements, <textarea> boxes and <select> elements`. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse.Hope this is what u meant mate

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car 
<div id="divToBeRefreshed">

</div>
```

JS

```
$("input[name=vehicle]").on('change',function(){
      $("#divToBeRefreshed").html($(this).val());
 });
```

if you  want to fire an event when a checkbox is checked / unchecked: use the below code too.

```
if( $(this).is(':checked') )
```

Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/BzgrW/